# SQLite: Selecting all rows with IDs from one table that match IDs in a different table

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables. Both have an `ID` column.

I want to select all rows in Table A that have an ID that matches an ID in Table b.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's called JOIN...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM TableB);
```